# nginx reverse proxy pass and redirect call within same location

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to configure nginx to make a REST API call do some validation on the incoming request and if the response is successful do the proxy pass to required upstream  within a 'location'

Also the REST API call to do the validation has to be a GET always whereas the incoming request to the upstream can be of any type (GET or POST or DELETE etc...).Also if i use a proxy_method to set the method  is it possible to reset it back to the original value.

location /shared/xyz {

```
 proxy_pass http://servername:port/shared/nginx/validate?service=xyz ;  will always be a GET
 proxy_redirect ^  http://upstreamservername ;   #can be any type GET or POSt etc..
```

}

Is there a possibilty to do this in nginx.

Thanks in advance.

-- james